# No operator "=" matches these operands - Iterators from the Standard Template Library

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-keyword, operands

Okay, I'm working on a project for school, and we need to have a linked list of a class within another class (a linked list of the class "task" inside a class called "objectives"), so for this i'm using the STL class . Now I *almost* have it set up, but in my display function, to display the contents of the tasks, I'm using an iterator. But I can't assign taskList.begin() to the iterator because it gives me an error.

The following is the code that I think is relevant.

objective.h

```
    #ifndef OBJECTIVE_H
    #define OBJECTIVE_H
    #include <string>
    #include <list>
    #include "date.h"
    #include "task.h"
    using namespace std;
    namespace team2
    {
      class objective
      {
            private:
                string objective_name, objective_desc, resources[10];
                int category, priority, res_used;
                double time;
                date start, end;
                int status;
                std::list<task> taskList;

            public:
                // CONSTRUCTORS
                objective();
                objective(string objN, string objD, int c, int p, date s, date e, double t, string res[], int resU, int stat, list<task>& tList);

...

                // CONSTANT MEMBER FUNCTIONS
                void display() const;
...
      };
    }
    #endif
```

objective.cpp (This is where I get the error)

```
#include "objective.h"
#include "date.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include "task.h"
using namespace std;

namespace team2
{
    void objective::display() const // display() - Displays the complete contents of a single objective
    {
        int days, hours, minutes;
        std::list<task>::iterator taskIterator;

        days = floor(time/24.0); // Find the max number of days based off of the time (in hours)
        hours = floor(time - days*24); // Find the max number of hours after deduction of days
        minutes = floor((time - (days*24 + hours))*60); // Find the number or minutes after taking into account hours and days

        cout << "\nObjective Name: " << objective_name << endl;
        cout << "Objective Description: " << objective_desc << endl;
        cout << "Category: Quad " << category << endl;
        cout << "Priority: " << priority << endl;
        cout << "Starting Date: " << start.getMonth() << "/" << start.getDay() << "/" << start.getYear() << endl;
        cout << "Ending Date: " << end.getMonth() << "/" << end.getDay() << "/" << end.getYear() << endl;
        cout << "Time Required: " << days << " Days " << hours << " Hours " << minutes << " Minutes " << endl;
        cout << "Resources: " << endl;
            if(res_used == 0)
                cout << "\tNo Resources" << endl;
            for(int i = 0; i < res_used; i++)
                cout << "\t" << resources [i] << endl;

        cout << "Current Status: ";
            if(status == 1)
                cout << "Completed" << endl;
            else if(status == 0)
                cout << "Incomplete" << endl;
        cout << "Tasks: " << endl;
            if(taskList.empty())
                cout << "\tNo Resources" << endl;
            for(taskIterator = taskList.begin(); taskIterator != taskList.end(); taskIterator++)
            {
                 (*taskIterator).display();
                 cout << endl;
             }
    }
}
```

The tasks class is almost Identical to the objective class, with a few fields omitted. The error occurs in the for loop. for(taskIterator = taskList.begin();...) Anyone know the cause for the problem? I can also provide more code if necessary. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The method is `const`, `taskList` is a member, so you can't have a non-`const` iterator on it.

Making a member method `const` is a contract that that method will not change non-`mutable` class members nor call non-`const` member methods. By having a non-`const` iterator, you're breaking that contract.

Since `display` is const, you can use a const iterator:

```
std::list<task>::const_iterator taskIterator;
```